OpenMP Program with Nested For-Loop in While-Loop Occasionally Hangs
I'm attempting to parallelize a for-loop within a while-loop using OpenMP and encountered an issue where the program intermittently hangs, especially when the condition variable approaches 1. Below is the simplified code snippet:
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void task(int thread_id, int condition) {
    printf("Hello from thread %d with condition %d\n", thread_id, condition);
}

int main() {
    int condition = 5;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) shared(condition)
    {
        while(condition) {
            #pragma omp master
            {
                // Update condition in master thread
                condition--;
                #pragma omp flush(condition)
            }
            #pragma omp barrier // Wait for master to update condition
    
            #pragma omp for
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                task(omp_get_thread_num(), condition);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Output example (hangs when condition is 1. Ideally, the program should stop when condition equals 0.):
Hello from thread 0 with condition 4
Hello from thread 1 with condition 4
Hello from thread 2 with condition 4
Hello from thread 3 with condition 4
Hello from thread 3 with condition 3
Hello from thread 1 with condition 3
Hello from thread 0 with condition 3
Hello from thread 2 with condition 3
Hello from thread 2 with condition 2
Hello from thread 3 with condition 2
Hello from thread 1 with condition 2
Hello from thread 0 with condition 2
Hello from thread 1 with condition 1
Hello from thread 3 with condition 1
Hello from thread 0 with condition 1
Hello from thread 2 with condition 1
...

Despite the use of #pragma omp flush(condition) to ensure the condition variable's visibility and #pragma omp barrier to synchronize threads, the program sometimes stalls, seemingly deadlocked, particularly when condition reaches 1. It appears that the while-loop does not exit as expected.
I've also tried adding an additional barrier at the end of the while-loop, but the issue persists. Could this be due to a deadlock or another synchronization issue? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

As long as there is no nowait clause on the omp for, it has an implicit barrier at the end, so it is expected that another explicit barrier after the for loop does not change the result.

Try to avoid specifying the number of threads in your code e.g. via the num_threads() clause. Instead rely on the user specifying the OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable so the number can be decided in a standardized way at runtime.

@paleonix Thank you for your insight! Implementing another barrier effectively resolved the issue.
Additionally, I have a follow-up question regarding the implementation of efficient parallelism within the for-loop inside the while-loop using OpenMP. The approach I'm currently using feels somewhat complex. I've experimented with omp task, but it seems that creating a task for each computation incurs significant overhead compared to chunk-based distribution in omp for.
Do you have any recommendations for efficiently parallelizing for-loops within a while-loop in OpenMP?

I don't see what you mean by "somewhat complex". Without seeing the actual amount of work and algorithm used, it will be impossible to give recommendations. Maybe open another question with more context/details?

@paleonix Thanks for your reply, I will open a new question to discuss this later!

None of the broadly used openmp implementations will kill the threads at the end of a parallel region. The performance of moving the parallel region into the while loop will not have a negative impact for your application performance. With implementation knowledge, I would actually expect a slight performance improvement for llvm/clang. To really understand the performance impact, you would need to do some performance experiments.

@Joachim You're right. I conducted some basic experiments, and indeed, there were no negative impacts observed!

Compiling the code like following reports the data race in your code:
$ clang -O3 -g -fopenmp -fsanitize=thread so-78260058.c
$ ./a.out
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=80729)
  Read of size 4 at 0x7ffee9bf9638 by thread T2:
    #0 main.omp_outlined_debug__ so-78260058.c:12:15 (a.out+0xe60b8)
    #1 main.omp_outlined so-78260058.c:10:5 (a.out+0xe6345)
    #2 __kmp_invoke_microtask <null> (libomp.so+0xbcbd2)
    #3 main so-78260058.c:10:5 (a.out+0xe6058)

  Previous write of size 4 at 0x7ffee9bf9638 by main thread:
    #0 main.omp_outlined_debug__ so-78260058.c:16:26 (a.out+0xe6101)
    #1 main.omp_outlined so-78260058.c:10:5 (a.out+0xe6345)
    #2 __kmp_invoke_microtask <null> (libomp.so+0xbcbd2)
    #3 main so-78260058.c:10:5 (a.out+0xe6058)

  Location is stack of main thread.

  Location is global '??' at 0x7ffee9bdb000 ([stack]+0x1e638)

  Thread T2 (tid=80732, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:1020:234 (a.out+0x5f1bb)
    #1 __kmp_create_worker <null> (libomp.so+0x9c096)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race so-78260058.c:12:15 in main.omp_outlined_debug__

The report is about a read in line 12 (while(condition) and a write in line 16 (condition--;). The column also clearly identifies the condition variable. The minimal change to fix the data race as discussed in the comments is to add a barrier before the master construct the flush is superfluous, and also the barrier after the master construct is not necessary, because of the implicit barrier at the end of the for region.
Easier to read is the following code:
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void task(int thread_id, int condition) {
  printf("Hello from thread %d with condition %d\n", thread_id, condition);
}

int main() {
  int condition = 5;
  while (condition) {
    condition--;

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
      task(omp_get_thread_num(), condition);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

Since most OpenMP implementations maintain a thread pool, the overhead of spawning the parallel regions is not significantly higher than the two necessary barriers. (if you use nested parallelism, check the KMP_HOT_TEAMS_MAX_LEVEL env variable)
